# How to get removed duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas

How to get removed duplicates Pandas after operation:

```
new_df.drop_duplicates()
```

To get specific column values by column name.

Also there is a complected condition:

```
df_filtered = new_dfr[filter1 & filter2 & filter3 & filter4]
```

I tried to get `False` rows using this:

```
df_filtered = ~new_dfr[filter1 & filter2 & filter3 & filter4]
```

I have tried also this:

```
df_filtered_false = new_dfr[~(filter1 & filter2 & filter3 & filter4)]
```

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to remove duplicates by column name?

Comment: Could you clarify "To get specific column values by column name." What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that filter returns true rows. With columns NUM AGE. But I need to get false rows and get column's value (NUM) to the list

Comment: Thanks. With due respect, there is not enough context for me to understand what you are referring to. Think of that we don't have your code or the problem you're trying to solve, in front of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```py
removed = df[df.duplicated()]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. could you check question again, I have added remark with the similar issue

Comment: @Mamed You need do `~(filter1 & filter2 & filter3 & filter4)`

Comment: Then to get column values like this? `removed['NUM'].values().tolist()`?

Comment: Why the negation? If we want all duplicates, then we want to look at `df[df.duplicated()]`

Comment: @Mamed If you want them as list, you can. Or `df.loc[df.duplicated(), 'NUM']`

Comment: @creanion Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thank you for `~(filter1 & filter2 & filter3 & filter4)`. Could you write full code? is it okey?   `newDf  = ~(filter1 & filter2 & filter3 & filter4)`?